# Cannot change static final variable

Tags: java, eclipse, playframework

```
public class TestData {
   public static final String DATA = "A"; // I change this to read DATA = "B"
}

public class MyTest extends UnitTest {
   private MyClass myClass;

   public void setUp() {
      myClass = new MyClass(TestData.DATA); // After change, DATA has value "B"
   }
}

public class MyClass {
   private String myVar;

   public MyClass(String myVar) { // After change, myVar still has value "A"
      this.myVar = myVar;   
   }
}
```

1. Change `TestData.DATA` to `B` by editing the source code in Eclipse
2. Restart server
3. Run `MyTest`
4. `MyClass` still receives `A` when referencing `TestData.DATA`
5. ???

Things I tried: restart server, eclipsify project, clean project, restart eclipse, restart computer, refresh every file manually. I found this to work:

```
String data = TestData.DATA;
myClass = new MyClass(data);
```

Why can't I pass DATA directly to MyClass constructor?

I've got no error messages, when I break at `setUp`, `DATA` has the value "B" since I've changed it, but when I step into MyClass `myVar` has the value "A"

Comment: Where's the constructor for MyClass?

Comment: What error message do you get when you pass DATA directly to the MyClass constructor?

Comment: Did you made the change in another program than eclipse editor?

Comment: I'm using Play-Framework plugin for Eclipse 3.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't change a `final` variable. That's what makes it `final`. But there is nothing wrong with passing the `final` variable to a function. In fact, the sample code that you posted runs just fine.

In your list of steps, you said 'change DATA to "B"' though your code doesn't show this step. But that's fine, since that step wouldn't compile.

If you need to alter a `final` variable before passing it to a function, you need to make a local copy and change that copy instead.

**Update:** Now that the question has been clarified, here are some more thoughts:

It sounds like something isn't being recompiled properly. Perhaps you are running from an old version of the classes (i.e. you need to copy it somewhere)?

Also, you should know that although you may change the `TestData` class, because `DATA` is declared `static final`, Java may have inlined that constant into the `MyTest` class (since it is guaranteed to never change) so you need to make sure that `MyTest` is also recompiled.

If you want to verify that you are using the latest version of a class, put some very "loud" code in a place where you know it should execute. For example, a `System.out.println` or even throw a `RuntimeException` (sure, your program will fail, but if it doesn't fail then you *know* that something isn't being recompiled properly which will help you diagnose what is wrong).

Comment: By changing DATA to "B" I meant in Eclipse manually rewriting it and re-running the test code.

Comment: @bizo09: did u re-compile the java files again ? It seems as if eclipse is somehow not compiling your new code. That is probably the reason why you are still seeing A being passed

Comment: @Adam Batkin I've stepped through the code with the debugger. In MyTest, DATA has the value "B", but in MyClass, myVar has value "A". Technically, MyClass hasn't changed, but if Java inlined it into MyClass constructor that might be an issue. How do I force MyClass to be recompiled in Play?

Comment: @Adam Batkin wow, adding a system.out.println did work and forced MyClass to recompile. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that all the `.java` files are being compiled between runs, Eclipse has a cache that gets out of sync some times. Doing a clean on the project should clear up your problems

Comment: I've tried to do a clean project, but Play compiles the java files on the fly. It's really frustrating, because once I declare a public static final variable, there's no way I can change its value literally. Not even by hand, lol.

Answer (score 1):

After changing the `TestData` class, you have to recompile the other classes. The reason is that constant expressions are resolved at compile time, not at run time.

Answer (score 1):

Try manually cleaning, does that work? Chances are its caching things on compilation and then not refreshing the contents when it should. I've seen similar behaviour with Netbeans over static final fields, and cleaning has generally solved it.

If this does prove the case, and a full build doesn't take too long, the easiest thing to do is probably modify the ant task so before every run it does a clean (and so is forced to recompile the classes it needs from scratch.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that your class gets recompiled to wherever your server is reading the class files from. It's cached somewhere, hence the old value of `DATA`.

Why do you say that you can't pass DATA to the MyClass constructor?